# Why does git track changes I never made by making a deletion then immediately adding it back?

Tags: git

Why is git deleting lines and then adding them back? I had this happen when I edited the file in Atom. I tried again in nano and was very careful to not change anything except for the one letter that was misspelled. Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Git works line-wise by default. In your first change you can see that actually just one word has changed, where the typo was corrected. This is marked with darker color. However this is done by the tokenizer and not Git *per se*. When it comes to edit conflicts during merge or rebase, lines are considered as a whole. There is no conflict resolution at single character level.

The second change in your example is most probably the last line in your file, and there was no line end after the last line. On the right hand side new empty line was added –so definitely a new character in this line, although not visible directly.

Comment: Git uses (essentially) content-addressable storage and as such is not line-wise, it's blobwise.

Answer (score 1):

It is not adding and deleting lines. It's not even git. That's a diff application, and it is showing characters (not lines) added and removed.

git knows that only what you changed has changed. The diff application is presenting that difference with a `+` or `-` marking the line and a dark green highlight marking the characters.  Nothing is saying that a line has been removed or added.